# Give an example where $\{a^2_n\}_{n=1}^\infty$ is a Cauchy sequence, but $\{a_n\}_{n=1}^\infty$is not.

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, cauchy-sequences

> Give an example where $\{a^2_n\}_{n=1}^\infty$ is a Cauchy sequence, but $\{a_n\}_{n=1}^\infty$is not.

Could somebody give me an example of this? Thanks in advance!

Comment: $1,-1,1,-1,\ldots$.

Comment: thats quite logic actually! thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

Take for example
$$a_n=(-1)^n$$